# I can't use libjson like n.push_back(JSONNode("RootA", "Hello World"));

Tags: c++, libjson

I download libjson_7.6.1.zip from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjson/, and compile it to generate a library.
After I create a new project , I find that I can't use libjson like that:
n.push_back(JSONNode("RootA", "Hello World"));//(JSONNode n(JSON_NODE);)

The error message shows that “JSONNode::JSONNode”: On an overloaded function call is not clear

It suggests JSONNode constructors as follows:

“JSONNode::JSONNode(const json_string &,bool)”

“JSONNode::JSONNode(const json_string &,json_number)”

“JSONNode::JSONNode(const json_string &,json_int_t)”

Is there something wrong with my libjson version ?

Or What did I miss ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You trying to push:

    JSONNode("RootA", "Hello World")

which is basically:

    JSONNode(const json_string&, const char*)

And if the compiler suggests you:

 - “JSONNode::JSONNode(const json_string &,bool)”
 - “JSONNode::JSONNode(const json_string &,json_number)”
 - “JSONNode::JSONNode(const json_string &,json_int_t)”

then why not to change the second paramter to either int or bool?

Comment: Not that I could help you, but can you provide a URL for that libjson? Reason is that the link associated with the "libjson" tag is for a different library for use in C.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution is to note "#define JSON_LIBRARY" in JSONOptions.h

I create a cpp file while I use c-library, I think that's the reason